# how install openoffice and unoconv in centos 5.9

Tags: openoffice.org

system is centos 5.9

```
rpm -qa | grep office
openoffice.org-headless-3.1.1-19.10.el5_8.4
openoffice.org-pyuno-3.1.1-19.10.el5_8.4
openoffice.org-ure-3.1.1-19.10.el5_8.4
openoffice.org-core-3.1.1-19.10.el5_8.4
openoffice.org-calc-3.1.1-19.10.el5_8.4
openoffice.org-sdk-3.1.1-19.10.el5_8.4

unoconv --version
unoconv 0.5
Written by Dag Wieers dag@wieers.com
Homepage at http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/

platform posix/linux2
python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan 9 2013, 06:47:03)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)]
OpenOffice.org 3.1
```

when i run unoconv

```
unoconv -l &

ps aux | grep soffice
root 24087 0.0 0.7 469220 43164 pts/0 Sl 03:29 0:00 /usr/lib64/openoffice.org3/program/soffice.bin -headless -invisible -nocrashreport -nodefault -nologo -nofirststartwizard -norestore -accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext

unoconv -f doc AdvancedTable.docx or
unoconv -f pdf test.doc
```

it will response error message to me

UNO IllegalArgument during import phase: Source file cannot be read. URL seems to be an unsupported one.

but i can install in centos 6.3

who can help me?